# Promise not getting resolved while sending http request

Tags: node.js, promise, q

I am calling func2(which should return promise) but promise is not getting resolved.Am I resolving promise wrongly or is there any other problem.Please let me know what is the problem in following code?

```
            function func1() {

                func2().then(function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                })

            }

            var func2 = function () {
                var d = q.defer();
                var postRequest = {
                    host: "abc",
                    path: "/xyz",
                };

                var buffer = "";

                var req = http.request( postRequest, function( res ) {  
                   var buffer = "";
                   res.on( "data", function( data ) {
                     console.log("data\n");
                     buffer = buffer + data; 
                   });
                   res.on( "end", function( data ) { 
                        d.resolve(data);
                        return d.promise;
                   });
                });

                console.log('after req');
                req.write(body);
                req.end();
            };
```

Comment: You're not returning the promise from your func2. You should do it not inside the callback, but in the end of the function

Comment: I want to resolve promise with the data obtained from http.request.If I resolve in the end it will be null.

Comment: You resolve it when you receive data, but you do `return d.promise` in the end of the function, so that you `then` statement works correctly

Comment: Don't you also want `d.resolve(buffer);` instead of `d.resolve(data);`?

Answer (score 3):

You need to return the promise at the very end of the function. Try

```
function func1() {

    func2().then(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }).catch(function (error) {
        // Handle any error from all above steps 
        console.log("Got error:" + error);
    })
    .done();

}

var func2 = function () {
    var d = q.defer();
    var postRequest = {
        host: "abc",
        path: "/xyz",
    };

    var buffer = "";

    var req = http.request( postRequest, function( res ) {  
       var buffer = "";
       res.on( "data", function( data ) {
         console.log("data\n");
         buffer = buffer + data; 
       });
       res.on( "end", function( data ) { 
            d.resolve(buffer);
       });
       res.on( "error", function( err ) { 
            d.reject(err);
       });
    });

    console.log('after req');
    req.write(body);
    req.end();

    return d.promise;

};
```

Comment: What was the problem? What did you change?

Comment: @Bergi I think this is quite obvious if you compare the code. I don't see a use in making this more complex as necessary. The question was very broad and normally should have been voted to close, so I chose to keep it short.

Comment: Ah, that single sentence helped me to spot the difference - thanks for the edit! I don't like comparing codes by hand :-)